# Is it permissible to post joke questions?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Consider:

[How can I make setTimeout work with negative numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60963011)

> I expect the message to show up -3000 milliseconds after I click the button, that is, three seconds before I click the button, but actually it shows up immediately after I click the button. It seems that setTimeout doesn't support a negative second argument.

This is clearly absurd, and everyone involved is aware of it - the question is a joke. I've been under the impression that these sorts of things don't have any place on Stack Overflow - people come here to discuss programming and solve problems, not to read jokes.

The question was closed, but later got reopened. Even if it were to be closed again, due to upvoted answer, it won't roomba. How will something like this benefit anyone a couple years (or a couple days) down the line?

Since the question and answer received a surprising number of upvotes for something that seemed to me to be obviously off-topic, and since it got reopened, I figured I'd ask here - is posting this sort of thing actually permissible under certain circumstances? (At time of posting, question was at +6/-2, answer was at +5/-2)

Comment: the question is well written that I start thinking about the issue ... I would say an *april fool*

Comment: It *shouldn't* be. We get enough bad questions as it is without giving new users the impression that this is ok.

Comment: It's absurd, but it's about programming, clear, and asks a precise question. And then there's [Stack Overflow: Where We Hate Fun](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/01/04/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/)

Comment: It can be safely downvoted tomorrow... Or by anyone from earlier time zones that are already in April 2nd...

Comment: It is possible though. You just use a heap spray, execute some code at the system level to alter the system time, and then watch the magic happen. Time is relative.

Comment: Don't worry -- by tomorrow, it'll have been deleted a week ago.

Comment: @Scratte That was posted over ten years ago. Besides, of the three guidelines there, it only passes the first one in the most superficial sense and fails the other two.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery It didn't fail the second at the time of creation of this post. I believe it's since been going through the motions of the "meta" effect. It's not completely useless either in my opinion, so I'm at a 50/50 on the last point.

Comment: @Scratte Even before the meta effect it had already been closed once and downvoted multiple times, and it still only has single-digit upvotes. That's hardly overwhelming community support. As for usefulness, I don't see how you could get anything useful out of this. At *best* it's a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430966/is-calling-settimeout-with-a-negative-delay-ok), so it would be closed anyway.

Comment: cross-site duplicate: [Dealing with “Find out who's going to buy the croissants”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190106/165773)

Comment: TBH I like to see the occasional joke amongst all serious questions here. Maybe put a little icon  in front to mark it as a joke. Reputation gain should be exempted though.

Comment: @Flame consider giving a read to [The Trouble With Popularity](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2012/01/the-trouble-with-popularity/) article written by Stack Overflow founder: "we discovered that these posts... truly start to drown out everything else on the site... it's too addictive and too easy, and in the absence of any moderation, the community would do nothing but add and upvote the easy, fun stuff..."